# How to get nifty and sensex data using Alpha Vantage api key

Tags: alpha-vantage

1. Is possible to get nifty 50 data using Alpha Vantage?
2. Also the current price of gold?

Answer (score 2):

1. As of now, Alpha Vantage only has 100% support for US ETFs, so to get NIFTY data you can download the 50 tickers, you can download the [list here](https://www.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_niftynext50list.csv), and then make a call to each ticker.
2. Yes, use the CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE function, and "from_currency=XAU" parameter. XAU is the symbol for gold.

Example:

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=XAU&to_currency=USD&apikey=KEY_HERE